# R: Sample each element of a vector with specific probability *elegantly*

Tags: r, random

I wish to sample each element of a vector with specific probability `p`. This is how I currently do it, I find it hard to believe this is the most elegant way:

```
vec <- letters[1:5]
p <- 0.8
sampInd <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(vec), prob = c(p, 1-p), replace = TRUE)
vec[sampInd]
[1] "c" "d" "e"
```

Another way using a Bernoulli distribution:

```
sampInd <- ifelse(rbinom(length(vec), 1, p) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
vec[sampInd]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "e"
```

Am I missing some `base` function to do this more elegantly or over complicating my use of `sample` or `rbinom`? Don't care much about speed, though it's always a nice thing to have.

Comment: Not sure if it's more elegant, but I think I'd do `vec[runif(length(vec))<p]`.

Comment: @Miff you should add this as answer, if nothing miraculous will come up, I'll accept it as to my judgement it *is* more elegant.

Comment: It's essentially the same as your second solution but you don't need to have `ifelse`. `vec[rbinom(length(vec), 1, p) == 1]`

Comment: See that's exactly the kind of thing I wanted to get out of this question, how silly of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Been over a day since @Miff commented with this answer so I'll write it down here:)

```
vec[runif(length(vec)) < p]
```

is the most elegant way I know at the moment.